# Sublime Text 3 and Processing 3

Tags: path, processing, sublimetext

I've been trying for hours now to setup sublime text 3 to work with processing and I always get the same error message when I try to run my code:

```
/usr/local/bin/processing-java: line 13: cd: /private/var/folders/dy/167sm04x4t9bq57s7dn84r1h0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/7A673DF0-C5E7-4641-94DA-4D58B6F9BC25/d/Processing-3.app/Contents/Java: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['processing-java', '--force', '--sketch=/Users/Admin/Desktop/test 1/build', '--output=/Users/Admin/Desktop/test 1/build/build-tmp', '--run']]
[dir: /Users/Admin/Desktop/test 1/build]
[path: /anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin]
```

I'm on macOS 10.15.3. Can someone point me in the right direction.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Trying _how_? There are plugins for sublime that set this up for you, so if you've been trying this yourself, why? Did you try https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Processing?

Comment: i did use it...

Comment: But you did not say this in your post, so remember to follow the guidelines on [asking a question](/help/how-to-ask) and don't just say that you've been trying something, explain what you've done so people don't have to ask about things you've already done.

Comment: Well..anyways. I did a fresh install of my operating system and it works now.

Comment: sounds like this question can be safely deleted, then.